# Inheritance static methods

Tags: java, casting, static, polymorphism, overriding

```
class Human {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Human(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public static void message() {
        System.out.println("I'm a human.");
    }
}
public class Child extends Human {
    public Child(String name, int age) {
        super(name, age);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child child = new Child("Billy", 3);
        child.message(); // prints i'm a child.
    }
}
```

How does the program know that message() exists in the Human class? please DO NOT only say "because Child class extends Human" explain in detail.... (note, message() is static )

Comment: “When we call message using human2, the JVM will check if there exist an instance method called message” — No, that’s already wrong: the JVM is not involved in the process of looking up a static method. It’s done at compile-time, using the static type.

Comment: The JVM is not involved in resolving static methods. The Java Compiler does it. The Java Compiler sees that `human2` is declared as `Human human2` and transforms `human2.message();` into `Human.message();`.

Comment: Oh.. okay, so does the compiler check then if message is an instance method and then when it knows that message is not an instance method, does it check the method area then ( to see if message is static) ? ( i want to know the details )

Comment: The compiler does not care about the method area. The method area only exists at runtime.

Comment: static methods can be hidden, not overriden.

Comment: Ohh... okay, so when the compiler encounters:  human2.message();  , the compiler will check if message exists in the Human class because human2 is of type Human and when it sees that message exists in the Human class, the compiler will "translate human2.message() to Human.message(); ?

Comment: There is no such thing in Java as 'overriding static methods'. Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 3):

There is no inheritance, and therefore no overriding of static methods.

What you are doing here is not overriding, it is ***masking***:  The `message()` method of class `Child` ***masks*** the `message()` method of class `Human`.

If you were using a halfway decent IDE it would be giving you warnings about the following:

- The `message()` method of class `Child` masks the `message()` method of class `Human`.
- The invocations of `message` via instances are unnormalized/irrational (misleading) and you should normalize/rationalize them (make them reflect the truth) as follows:

  - `human1.message()` should be replaced with `Human.message()`.
  - `human2.message()` should be replaced with `Child.message()`.
  - `child.message()` should be replaced with `Child.message()`.

Static methods do not mix with inheritance; if you are ever doing anything at all which involves both static methods and inheritance, then ***in almost all certainty*** you are doing something wrong.

Comment: In the exampe you provided, doesn't that mean child.message() will be seen as Child.message() , which doesnt exist in the Child class... 

Comment: @NinaJava Child.message() *does* exist in the Child class.  All public methods are inherited, and all inherited methods are considered part of the public interface of a class.

Comment: I believe only instance methods and instance fields are inherited, not static methods/fileds ( because static members have  nothing to do with inheritance)

Comment: @NinaJava that is correct.  Statics are not inherited, and therefore cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

The message methods, when defined as static, are part of the class, they are not related to the instance that you create (Human or Child). Since you are defining `Human human2`, you are giving the compiler the hint to use the class method from the Human class. As soon as you are using `Child child` as type definition, the Java Compiler will relate to the Child class and use its class method.

Comment: But if i remove the message() method from the Child class and then type:  Child child = new Child("Billy", 3);
        child.message(); the code still works.... how is that possible ? i do know that the Child class extends the Human class but how is inheritance related to static members??

Answer (score 0):

In your program the class **Human** inherits **Child** This allow the **Child** class to access all methods from its super class **Human** . here is the way to differentiate **message()** methods.

```
Human human2 = new Child("Billy", 3);
human2.message(); // prints i'm a human.
```

The above **human2** object with **Child()** Constructor access the **message()** of the super class **Human**

```
 Child child = new Child("Billy", 3);
 child.message(); // prints i'm a child.
```

The above **child** object with **Child()** Constructor access the **message()** of the  class **Child**

Remember the concept of inheritance only objects of the child class **Child** can access members of the super class **Human**

```
Child child = new Human("Billy", 3);
 child.message(); // prints i'm a human.
```